# Datatable full row inline edit

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am working on a DataTable where allow user to add new/modify and delete data. BUt save the final data to database only at the end of the page.

Can i know when i click on a cell, how do that enable all textboxes in the entire row to be in editable mode? And when i mouse out of that row or press on tab at the last column of that row, how do it disable the editing mode of that row?

The online example only allow edit by column - https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.

I tried to modify the `.Edit` in Content\assets\pages\scripts\table-datatables-editable.js to below. I can see the row is in editable, but it dont allow me to edit and how do it enable the mouse in and mouse out?

```
table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
```

Become

```
table.on('click', 'tbody > tr > td', function (e) {
```

To disable the editing mode after mouse out and tab out from the last column, below is what I try:

```
$(this).childern().first().blur(function() {
     saveRow(oTable,nRow);
});
```

Comment: Why do you want this behavior? Is it because you don't want to submit the data after each cell is edited? If that's the case, then don't submit the changes after an edit. Submit on button click, for example. Frankly, I think it would look a little weird to have the cells in edit mode when they don't have the focus. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Karl, I need this behavior for my invoice page where I allow user to submit the overall changes at the bottom of the page. Having all cells in a row in edit mode will save the click entry where user can just press tab to move to next cell in a row.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think it will solve your problem. The DataTables site has this [tab between columns](http://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/tabControl.html) example in the Editor documentation. I use it along with the submit full row data option and I think it works well. Probably better so than modifying the code which would have to be maintained. (There is also an [Excel like](https://datatables.net/extensions/keytable/) extension `KeyTable` which I've not tried)